# botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (default) could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I'm facing issue while export CSV from pandas datafram to S3, getting below error:

The config profile (default) could not be found: ProfileNotFound
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (default) could not be found

Below aws cli setup in my local:
config :
[default]
region = us-west-1

credentials :
[default]
aws_secret_access_key =
aws_access_key_id =

Please help, thanks in advance

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem (for another application) and the only way I found to “fix” it was to create a new profile in my **~/.aws/config** file.

```
[profile mynewprofile]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXX
```

Then I modificated the script calling my `default` profile to `mynewprofile`.

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't apply to most people but I had the same error. I had set [`AWS_PROFILE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) as a permanent system environment variable on my Windows machine... and forgot. If your os has `AWS_PROFILE` set somewhere, you might see this error message.

> **AWS_PROFILE**
>
> Specifies the name of the AWS CLI profile with the credentials and options to use. This can be the name of a profile
> stored in a credentials or config file, or the value default to use
> the default profile.
>
> If defined, this environment variable overrides the behavior of using the profile named [default] in the configuration file. You can
> override this environment variable by using the --profile command line
> parameter.

[AWS Article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)